# Backtracking recursively with multiple solutions

Tags: recursion, backtracking

```
function BACKTRACKING-SEARCH(csp) returns a solution, or failure 
       return RECURSIVE-  BACKTRACKING({ }, csp)
function RECURSIVE-BACKTRACKING(assignment,csp) returns a solution, or failure 
       if assignment is complete then 
                 return assignment
       var ←SELECT-UNASSIGNED-VARIABLE(VARIABLES[csp],assignment,csp)
       for each value in ORDER-DOMAIN-VALUES(var,assignment,csp) do
                 if value is consistent with assignment according to CONSTRAINTS[csp] then
                           add {var = value} to assignment
                           result ← RECURSIVE-BACKTRACKING(assignment, csp)
                           if result ̸= failure then 
                                            return result
                           remove {var = value} from assignment 
       return failure
```

This is a backtracking recursion algorythm pseudocode from AIMA. However, I don't understand if it returns ALL possible solutions or just first one found. In case it is the last option, could you please help me modify it to return a list of possible solutions instead (or at least updating some global list).

EDIT: I implemented this algorithm in Java. However, there is one problem:

if I don't return assignment, but save it in **result** instead, the recursion stop condition fails (i.e. it doesn't exist anymore). How can I implement another stop-condition? Maybe I should return **true** in the end?

Here is my code :

```
/**
 * The actual backtracking. Unfortunately, I don't have time to implement LCV or MCV,
 * therefore it will be just ordinary variable-by-variable search.
 * @param line
 * @param onePossibleSituation
 * @param result
 */
public static boolean recursiveBacktrack(Line line, ArrayList<Integer> onePossibleSituation, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result){


if (onePossibleSituation.size() == line.getNumOfVars()){
    // instead of return(assignment)
    ArrayList<Integer> situationCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    situationCopy.addAll(onePossibleSituation);
    result.add(situationCopy);
    onePossibleSituation.clear();
}

Block variableToAssign = null;
// iterate through all variables and choose one unassigned
for(int i = 0; i < line.getNumOfVars(); i++){
     if(!line.getCspMiniTaskVariables().get(i).isAssigned()){
         variableToAssign = line.getCspMiniTaskVariables().get(i);
         break;
     }
}

// for each domain value for given block   
for (int i = line.getCspMiniTaskDomains().get(variableToAssign.getID())[0]; 
        i <= line.getCspMiniTaskDomains().get(variableToAssign.getID())[0]; i++){

    if(!areThereConflicts(line, onePossibleSituation)){
        //complete the assignment
        variableToAssign.setStartPositionTemporary(i);
        variableToAssign.setAssigned(true);
        onePossibleSituation.add(i);
        //do backtracking
        boolean isPossibleToPlaceIt = recursiveBacktrack(line,onePossibleSituation,result);
        if(!isPossibleToPlaceIt){
            return(false);
        }
    }

    // unassign
    variableToAssign.setStartPositionTemporary(-1);
    variableToAssign.setAssigned(false);
    onePossibleSituation.remove(i);

}

// end of backtracking
return(false);

}
```

Comment: updated my answer about your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code checks if solution found and if it is, returns the solution. Otherwise, continue backtracking. That means, it returns the first solution found.

```
if result ̸= failure then 
    return result
remove {var = value} from assignment
```

You can modify it like that:

```
if result ̸= failure then 
    PRINT result // do not return, just save the result
remove {var = value} from assignment
```

Or, better, modify this part:

```
if assignment is complete then 
    print assignment
    return assignment // print it and return
```

About edited question:

First, return `true` in the first `if`, so recursion will know that it found a solution. The second step, there is a mistake, probably:

```
if(!isPossibleToPlaceIt){
    return(false);
}
```

Should be

```
if(isPossibleToPlaceIt){
    return(true);
}
```

Because if your backtracking has found something, it returns `true`, which means you don't have to check anything else any longer.

**EDIT#2**: If you want to continue backtracking to find **ALL** solutions, just remove the whole previous `if` section with `return`:

```
//if(isPossibleToPlaceIt){
//    return(true);
//}
```

So we will continue the search in any way.

Comment: Sorry, but how do we stop recursion in this case? The return(assignment) was used as the final stop condition.

Comment: yes, do not remove return, use both return and print, like in the answer :) Does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't need print here. what I need is to store this found onePossibleSolution in **result** field

Comment: No, I haven't edited your answer, not even a letter. sorry if something is wrong...

Comment: I meant question :) Just return `true` in the first `if` block, so recursion will stop.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! =) Right, there comes a mistake. Actually I was translating from Python (see [AIMA code base](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/python/csp.html)) and forgot that my boolean variable contains opposite value to that one =)

Comment: Sorry again. If my backtracking found something, I need an opposite thing : to continue search until all solutions are found.It's about your last edit.

Comment: ok, added another edit :) Actually, I've already mentioned that in the very first answer, while talking about the pseudo code. Just remove the return, that's it.

Comment: Oh yes I am so demanding =) Thanks, I'll try to understand it.

Comment: Also, it seems like a mistake too: the code under `//unassign` should be inside enclosing `if`, I think. Although, it doesn't really matter in **this** implementation. :)